# Edge Browser in IE Mode is throwing an Error Message "Internet Explorer cant be found. You need to re-install or re-enable Internet Explorer""

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

My application doesn't work in the Edge browser. but works fine in the Edge Browser(Version 105) with IE Compatibility Mode. Am using Selenium 4 with below code to launch the Edge Browser in IE Mode
Note: IE 11 is not installed in the machine.
After launching the browser in the IE mode getting this error message ""Internet Explorer cant be found. You need to re-install or re-enable Internet Explorer" Attached the image
[image]

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", GlobalSettings.IE_DRIVER_PATH);
        InternetExplorerOptions IEOptionsEdge = setInternetExlopererForEdge();
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IEOptionsEdge);
driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

private static InternetExplorerOptions setInternetExlopererForEdge() 
{
    InternetExplorerOptions IEOptions  = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    IEOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
    IEOptions.ignoreZoomSettings();
    IEOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
    return IEOptions;
}
```

Note: I dont IE 11 listed in the Windows feature to turn on. am Using the WIndows 2016 Oracle VM

Error message in console

```
Jun 15, 2023 10:03:42 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'XYZ', ip: '123'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, se:ieOptions: {ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ignoreZoomSetting: true}}]}]
Capabilities {}
```

Comment: so, either make sure IE is present, or don't run it in IE modus.

Comment: I have also tried that. When i have IE11 installed along with Edge. When i run the code. Both IE and Edge browser(IE Mode) browser opens at same time and also Edge Browser(IE Mode) does not launch the URL. i have also enable the enterprise Mode with SIte List

Comment: so don't open it in IE mode

Comment: My application doesn't work in Edge browser without IE Mode and needs IE Mode in Edge Browser. This is the reason why am trying to run in IE Mode

Comment: then from my point of view, the better solution would be to improve your application

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion. I would need a solution for this question .  We cannot go and change the application and also when EDGE provides the support in IE mode . i Will wait or investigate for the answer

Comment: So...you do have IE installed on your Windows 2016, right? Are you able to see the iexplore.exe?

Comment: I have two instances of VM now. Cloned it. One version i have the IE11 installed and in another version i dont have IE11 installed

1. When IE 11 installed
When i run the code. Both IE and Edge browser(IE Mode) browser opens at same time and also Edge Browser(IE Mode) does not launch the URL. i have also enable the enterprise Mode with SIte List 
2. When IE 11 is not installed - Getting the error message "Internet Explorer cant be found. You need to re-install or re-enable Internet Explorer""
 
 -

Comment: @SeleniumLover I'm back. Generally speaking, you need to install IE 11 first to make sure everything works. You've mentioned that "Both IE and Edge browser(IE Mode) browser opens at same time and also Edge Browser(IE Mode) does not launch the URL". Would you please try [disabling IE11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-disable-ie11#disable-internet-explorer-11-as-a-standalone-browser)? Also, is there any error message when "Edge Browser(IE Mode) does not launch the URL"?

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing your project navigating to any URL in your code. Is it omitted?

Comment: I have added the URL now in the question. missed that park.

Comment: @SeleniumLover I tried your code in Windows Server 2016, but failed to replicate your issue. Can you see any error message in the console?

Comment: Hope you are trying in windows 2016 Server with Edge alone installed and doesn't have IE. I have updated the question with error message am facing as you requested

Comment: @SeleniumLover I have tested on Windows Server 2016 with or without IE installed. The result is I can only launch the project with IE installed because IE mode is dependent on IE just like I said before. As to the error message you've just provided, please make sure that your IEDriver is not blocked by Windows Defender or the like.

Comment: Okay then i have installed the IE in another machine and has been trying that to launch the Edge but facing the issue where it opens both IE and Edge at same time.  and doesnt launch the browser. I have raised a bug in Selenium github.com
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12171#issuecomment-1594366169

Comment: @SeleniumLover I have checked your issue post on GitHub, and it seems to be the proxy restriction because normally only IE mode instance shows up. Have you checked that? How does it turn out now?